# double declining depreciation in java

Tags: java, math

I am working on a simple console based program to calculate depreciation over set time interval. I allready have the code for my single-line depreciation( where it is depreciated 1/nth of its origonal value). I am having trouble with the double depreciation though(where it is depreciated by its new price at the start of every year)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class Number6 {

public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  int year = 2001;
  int lifeSpan = 3;
  int limit = year + lifeSpan -1 ;
  double cost = 1500;
  double depreciation = cost/lifeSpan;
  double totalDepreciation  = 0;

System.out.println("Enter The Method Of Depriciation (straight-line or double-declining)");
String method = scan.next();

System.out.println("Please Enter The Description Of The Prodect");
String desc = scan.next();

System.out.println("Please Enter The Year Of The Product");
year = scan.nextInt();

System.out.println("Please enter cost of prodect");
cost = scan.nextInt();

System.out.println("Please Enter Years Of Depreciation");
lifeSpan = scan.nextInt();


 NumberFormat nf =  NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

 System.out.println("Description: "+ desc);
 System.out.println("Year Of Purchase: "+ year);
 System.out.println("Cost Of Purchase: "+ cost);
 System.out.println("Estimated Life: "+ lifeSpan) ;
 System.out.println("Method Of Depreciation: "+ method);


 if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("straight-line")){//basically this while loop is for the fisrt type of depreciation
  while(year <= limit)
  {
      System.out.print(year + "\t");
      System.out.print(nf.format(cost) + "\t\t\t");
      depreciation = cost/lifeSpan;
      System.out.print(nf.format(depreciation) + "\t\t\t");
      totalDepreciation += depreciation;
      System.out.print(nf.format(totalDepreciation) + "\n");
      cost -= depreciation;
      year++;
  }
 }else if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("double-declining")){




     //but this is where the other type of depreciation that I cannot figure out would go


 }

 scan.close();

}

}
```

Comment: could you tell us what really bothering you? cuz may be it is me but I did not understand what troubling you

Comment: @KickButtowski you are not alone

Comment: Wow... September... StudentOverflow

Comment: @EddieB absolutely nothing is wrong with students nor homework questions.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Whos said something was wrong? The question should be tagged as homework... but there's absolutely nothing wrong with students. Ever.

Comment: @EddieB The homework tag has been removed.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Oh. I digress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that you need to calculate a depreciation for each year, based on the current book value of the item:

```
double depreciationRate = 0.3;  // 0.3 assumes a 30% depreciation each year

 }else if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("double-declining")){
  while(year <= limit)
  {
      System.out.print(year + "\t");
      System.out.print(nf.format(cost) + "\t\t\t");
      depreciation = cost*depreciationRate;                      // This is the "magic" - n% of the book value, so a new value is calculated for each year.
      System.out.print(nf.format(depreciation) + "\t\t\t");
      totalDepreciation += depreciation;
      System.out.print(nf.format(totalDepreciation) + "\n");
      cost -= depreciation;
      year++;
  }
```